# Custom Filtering On CheckBox Check Changed - Telerik RadGrid Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I have a `Rad Grid` which will fill from database.
I have a `check box` which will filter some rows in its checked mode.
I have a `list of strings` which contains some specific IDs.

Here is the Grid:

```
ID     Name
------------
1      John
2      Steve
3      Joe
4      Sara
```

Here is the List of strings:

```
"2","4"
```

I need when the checkbox is checked filter those rows which their ID exists in this list.

```
private void checkMajor_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkMajor.Checked)
        // Here will be the custom filter
    else
        this.gridShopList.Columns["IDCol"].FilterDescriptor = new FilterDescriptor();
}
```

How to do such thing? and more over How to make complex Custom Filtering on rows?

Comment: Is [this](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/filtering/setting-filters-programmatically-(simple-descriptors)) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see how to filter the grid by more then one condition: [CompositeFitlerDescriptor](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/filtering/setting-filters-programmatically-(composite-descriptors))

Here is a sample:

```
        List<string> list = new List<string>() {"2", "4"};

        CompositeFilterDescriptor compositeFilter = new CompositeFilterDescriptor();
        compositeFilter.LogicalOperator = FilterLogicalOperator.Or;

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            compositeFilter.FilterDescriptors.Add(new FilterDescriptor("ID", FilterOperator.IsEqualTo, item));
        }

        this.radGridView1.Columns["IDCol"].FilterDescriptor = compositeFilter;
```

Comment: Nice conversion of comment to answer.  Well done.  Except that link-only answers are unacceptable.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Thank you for your link. It was nice. But I do not think checho convert your comment into his answer, He answered my question related to telerik components several times and I know He is professional as well ;)

Comment: @Stranger Doesn't change the point:  the link was already provided and the answer adds nothing.  [Read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @DonBoitnott - the link you provided is for simple descriptors, while the question is for complex ones, as the link I provided shows just this. I will also add code.